# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

Tags: kotlin, view

Hy guys,
I am pretty new to Kotlin and am trying to check if an inflated View already exists. If so, I want to remove it and replace it with another inflate.

Problem is, that I try to check if this Element exists as in JavaScript style, but - however - this approach does not work in Kotlin. It creates the following Error in my Run-Log:

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

Actual snippet of code that creates this error:

```
   val tableParentFallbackView = (highlightedTable?.parent as ViewGroup) as LinearLayout

        if(tableParentFallbackView?.findViewById(R.id.highlight_number_1)) {
            tableParentFallbackView.removeView(findViewById(R.id.highlight_number_1))
        }
```

So question is: **How to check if a View already exists in Kotlin?** ^^

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are using a `TableLayout?` as a boolean. Instead you need to check if it is not null like:
`tableParentFallbackView?.findViewById(R.id.highlight_number_1) != null`

Comment: that was exactly my first guess, but IDE keeps breaking up Gradle build with the Error Message: "Not enough information to infer type variable T"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with some help in the comments I figured out the Solution. I tried to select a LinearLayout in a TableLayout - and therefore I had to TypeCast the Selector like this:

```
   if(tableParentFallbackView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.highlight_number_1) != null) {
            tableParentFallbackView.removeView(findViewById(R.id.highlight_number_1))
        }
```

Thx for the support - I hope it will help someone in the future, fixing a similar problem ^^